# Exporting an interactive map to web/online

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, online, interaction

I have made a map on QGIS for staff locations and symbolised the points by their job position, then created new layers for each position. I then used the qgis2web plugin to export it, but didn't realise that you can't share it with people or upload the link to a website because to everyone else it comes up blank. Is there a way to export a map online so that it can be shared with people who can click on points and find the data attributed to it e.g. staff name etc., and have the legend so people can click on and off layers they don't want to look at e.g. tick off assistants and only look at senior members of staff?

Comment: you need to either share the entire folder with other people or start a server and serve the map from there.

Comment: What exactly did you do that did not work satisfactory?

Comment: @DrorBogin I have tried sharing the entire folder but it still comes up blank for everyone else. How do I start a server and do that?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I want to share it with other people so they can see our staff locations but the map turns out blank for them when I share via link or file or even when I share the entire folder

Comment: one very easy thing: export it as PDF with the geospatial option enabled. Then people have all the attributes and layers within the PDF

Comment: @eurojam Thank you. It worked but it's not quite what I want. I still want to be able to zoom in and out of the scale and click on the points to find their data not sift through the layers in the legend to find the data I need, it isn't practical or interactive.

Comment: How exactly do you "share"? Do you send them a link? A file? A directory?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have tried sending a link, sharing the file and sending the folder that the qgis2web plugin has exported in both emails and using share on onedrive where I have the folder and the html and other files stored. I know that maps exported with that plugin cannot be shared with other people so now I am just trying to figure out if there is another plugin that can work instead. I have tried Mappia but that hasn't worked for me either

Comment: I have managed to get it working with the qgis cloud plugin now. Thank you all anyway

Comment: I hope you are aware that everyone can see the map you uploaded to QGIS Cloud, the data is publically on the internet. If that was unintended, make sure you delete it!
qgis2web maps can be shared, that's basically the point of the plugin. Since you mention OneDrive, I assume that this made a mess of it. Did you try sending a ZIP archive of the full folder qgis2web created to someone? Do you want to copy the map or is it supposed to be in one central location for everyone?